# One Ref for multiple elements

Tags: reactjs, typescript

How can I define a ref for multiple elements? Only one of the elements is shown at a time.

```
interface InputProps {
  value: string,
  multiline: boolean,
  onchange?: (value: string) => void
}

interface InputApi {
  focus: () => void
}    

const Input = forwardRef<InputApi, InputProps>(function(props){

  let ref = useRef<HTMLElement>(null);

  useImperativeHandle(ref, () => {
    return {
      focus: () => ref.current?.focus(),
      value: ref.current?.value
    }
  });

  if(props.multiline){
    return <textarea ref={ref} value={props.value} onChange={e => props.onchange?.(e.target.value)} />
  }
  return <input ref={ref} value={props.value} onChange={e => props.onchange?.(e.target.value)} />
});
```

In my case HTMLElement is also not usable, because it does not have a value prop.
How can I define that all HTMLElement which have value and focus() are valid for ref?
Something like the following:

```
interface InputRef {
  focus: Function,
  value: string
}
let ref = useRef<InputRef>(null);
```

Playground can be found [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDGMA0cDecBm0A7ilACbL7YCuAzkpTfQJLhJQozABuSAEigB2ZADZI4AXwJQIIOACIoqDPIDcAKHXBBMdvnTjmgsNRgAFGWFq51cONxQjqSAFxxaMKNoDmmW3BBqES4RbVc4ACMICDEhPzsIQTQACyFvJAB+NwAKBydwjy9BbwBKOABeAD57CGAydQlNbV0ofTRDY1MAQTBgGztCNDocsqqauoamnT0DOCMTGEp+gggh2jcAMWokrkT4+0dnN0KfSc00RI85zvhygeJSCiR8AB557t7sd-NLWkrs-DbDDARLZMC-bAoXolHCaOwAenhYngSnwFTgdAYzzeN0o-0EQREJQ0dmRcFR6MxlBefAAKgBZAAyAFExCAkDp8YTiXCMSw2BwuLwBMIxNkocBsNlRtVYXY7EoYNQoIJlvKVmsRhVqqiAHRDKBKHQZXWDOjS-bqvJHcnPfXKo0wE3WpD+OyNd08-zAfBg366wLBYChQRIGFu21KlVwF66AAeMFIqFt+HKOFRUhdafBECsupdUkSAGFUsUkGnxGMc3nEik0plddkkLrE1B0jB84cw1J4ZV-B7I8rVS9tAsU2mMwd8tn-QW4MXS+kK9q4NXaLra4uG02W6R2538iUe32JF6kHHILA4GRniggvBvqogA)

Comment: You can try `useRef<HTMLInputElement | HTMLTextAreaElement>(null)`

Comment: @Eldar That does not work, both ref attributes of input and textarea are throwing error.

Comment: Then you can try `useRef<HTMLInputElement & HTMLTextAreaElement>(null)` :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use extend to inherit  HTMLELEMENT props into your custom interface and use it. Sample code:

```
interface InputRef extends HTMLElement {
   focus: ()=>void,
   value: string
 }
```

Also you can use "or" operator to have flexibility in type declaration. Like this:

```
let ref = useRef<InputRef | HTMLELEMENT | HTMLTextAreaElement| HTMLInputElement>(null);
```

**Updated answer**

You can inherit multiple props using extend and if the classes/interfaces have same attributes with types, you can omit those from one of the interface(according to your need). This small interface declaration would help you get the idea.

```
interface inputref extends Omit<HTMLElement,"addEventListener" | "removeEventListener">
 ,Omit<HTMLTextAreaElement,"type"| "selectionStart"|"selectionEnd" 
|"addEventListener"|"removeEventListener"|"labels"| 
"selectionDirection">
,HTMLInputElement
 {
     input:string
   }
```

Comment: That does not work, both ref attributes of input and textarea are throwing error. Error from textarea ref attribute: Type 'InputRef' is missing the following properties from type 'HTMLTextAreaElement': autocomplete, cols, defaultValue, dirName, and 25 more.

Comment: I have updated my comment, that might help you with it.